# Why does it follow that $s_p$ is a geodesic symmetry?

Tags: differential-geometry

In Helgason, pg $205.$, he states:

[image]

,where $s_p$ is a involutive isometry which leaves the point $p$ fixed, and $p$ is an isolated fixed point.

I cannot understand two things:

1. Why, if $X \neq 0$ belong to $V^+$, $s_p$ will leave the geodesic with initial velocity $X$ pointwise fixed.
2. Why $A=-I$ implies that $s_p$ is a geodesic symmetry.

It seems to me that this is where it enters the fact that $s_p$ is an isometry, but I cannot see how. My guess is that $2.$ will follow from his Lemma $11.2.$, which states:

[image]

But I have no idea about number $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The* geodesic symmetry at $p$ reverses the geodesics through $p$. So the derivative of such a map must be precisely negative the identity map.

If $AX=X$ and $X\ne 0$, then certainly $A(cX)=cX$ for all scalars $c$. So $s_p$ will fix the entire curve $\exp_p(cX)$, $c\in\Bbb R$. In particular, since local isometries preserve lengths of (local) curves, they must map (pieces of) geodesics to (pieces of) geodesics.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for helping.

I understand that the geodesic symmetry must have derivative $-I$. That was not the question, the question was the converse (which I think is answered by the lemma I mentioned).

And I don't understand how $A(cX)=cX$ implies that $s_p$ will fix the curve $\exp_p (cX)$ .

Comment: This follows immediately from the fact that $s_p$ is a local isometry, doesn't it?

Comment: Sorry, but I must be overlooking something. This isn't clear to me. How can I guarantee that $s_p(a)=a$ for every point of the geodesic, only with information about the derivative of $s_p$ on $p$?

Comment: @Aloizio, as you realized, the easiest approach is that local isometries must map (pieces) of geodesics to geodesics because arclength is preserved, and hence (locally) shortest paths must map to other shortest paths.

Comment: Thanks! Could you add this to your answer?